# can 2 sharepoint sites share access to the same Web part in SharePoint 2013?

Tags: sharepoint-designer

can 2 sharepoint sites share access to the same Web part in SharePoint 2013? We have a task list we would like to share access to across 2 different Sharepoint pages from different groups with in our company. I am wondering if that is possible to shaer the access to the second site/page similar to a data share webpart.

Answer (score 0):

You can share the list hwoever you want, then you can create a content query webpart in 2 different sites that point to that list, and it will trim security automatically.

Content query webpart, is normally for list or libraries in the same site collection.